# Sintaxis correcta de python

Tags: python, sintaxis

Estoy pasando de PHP a Python y en PHP los ciclos y condicionales normalmente se limitan con `{}`, pero en Python no encuentro algo que limite un bucle y llegué a pensar que solo es con la sintaxis. Tengo el siguiente código y no se si esta bien tabulado.

```
import requests
import pymysql
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np

connection = pymysql.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
password="",
db="base de datos"
)

#CÓDIGO
i=1
while i<10
  #CÓDIGO
  #CÓDIGO
  #CÓDIGO
  if a==1:
    print ("Hola1")
  elif a==2:
    print ("Hola2")
  elif a==3:
    print ("Hola3")
  elif a==4:
    print ("Hola4")
  #CÓDIGO
  it2=1
  while z<8:
    #CÓDIGO
    if g=="cadena":
      #CÓDIGO
      #CÓDIGO
    it +=1
  #CÓDIGO
  #CÓDIGO
  i +=1
```

Notese que no uso else, no se si es correcto hacerlo o una mala practica, pues no deseo que se haga nada si no se cumple la condición, traté de ponerle `pass` pero me mandó error.
Pusé #CÓDIGO debido a que el código es grande e iba a tardar mucho en leerlo.

Comment: En python la forma de delimitar los ciclo, condicionales, etc es a traves de la indentacion. Te recomiendo leer https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

Answer (score 1):

en efecto, en python las líneas y bloques de código se diferencian por la indentación. Lo que podría "sustituir" a las llaves de apertura `{` en otros lenguajes son los dos puntos `:` que se usan en los condicionales como muestras en tu código, pero también en los ciclos, por ejemplo un while

```
while i < 10:
    # hacer algo
```

O un for:

```
for elem in lista:
    # hacer algo
```

Respecto a la identación es correcta, puedes usar los espacios que gustes, siempre y cuando seas consistente con su uso.

Answer (score 1):

en el ciclo while, faltan los dos puntos para indicar un bloque, debería ser:

```
while i<10:
  #CÓDIGO
```

el bloque if está vacío; una solución sería:

```
if g=="cadena":
  pass
  #CÓDIGO
```

para limitar ciclos o bloques de código se usa la identación,
más info en:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/